# On compiling I get #endif without #if error. Here is the code. Please help!

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, sensors

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#endif
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define watersensor D2
const char* ssid = "pooja";
const char* password = "ranip2780@";
WiFiServer server(301);
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 43, 67);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 43, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(192, 168, 43, 1);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.config(ip, dns, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
}

void loop()
{
  // Check if a client has connected
  < WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while (!client.available()) {
    //    delay(1);
    client.setNoDelay(1);
  }

  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("");
  client.println("");
  client.println("<html>");
  client.println("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='20'>");
  client.println("<title>WATER OVERFLOW ALARM WITH ONLINE UPDATES</title>");
  client.println("<center>");
  client.println("<style>");
  client.println("H1 {");
  client.println("background-color: blue;");
  client.println("}");
  client.println("</style>");
  client.println("<H1 style='color:white'><table>");
  client.println("<tr>");
  client.println("<td><div class='inner'><font size= '+3' color='white'><b>");
  client.println("WATER OVERFLOW ALARM WITH ONLINE UPDATES<br>");
  client.println("USING NODEMCU 1.0 BOARD</font></b>");
  client.println("</div></td>");
  client.println("<td><div class='relative'>");

  if (digitalRead(watersensor) == LOW)
  {
    client.println("<button style='background-color:red;width:200px;height:100px'><font size= '+2' color='white'><b>FULL LEVEL ALERT</b></font></button><br>");
  }
  else
  {
    client.println("<button style='background-color:gray;width:200px;height:100px'<font size= '+2' color='white'><b>NOT FULL</b></font></button><br>");
  }

  client.println("</div></td>");
  client.println("</tr>");
  client.println("</table><hr></center>");
  client.println("<body style = 'background-color:lightgray;'>");
  client.println("<br>");
  client.println("<style>");
  client.println("div.relative {");
  client.println("position: relative;");
  client.println("left:100px;");
  client.println("}");
  client.println("div.inner {");
  client.println("position: relative;");
  client.println("left:10px;");
  client.println("}");
  client.println("div.sample1 {");
  client.println("position: relative;");
  client.println("left:85px;");
  client.println("}");
  client.println("</style><hr><br>");
  client.println("<b>LEGENDS: </b> <button style='background-color:gray;width:100px;height:50px'><font color='white'<b>NOT FULL</b></font></button>");
  client.println("<font color='black'><b>WATER LEVEL IS BELOW SENSOR.</b></font><p>");
  client.println("<div class='sample1'><button style='background-color:red;width:100px;height:50px'><font color='white'><b>FULL LEVEL ALERT</b></font></button><font color='black'><b> WATER LEVEL IS ALREADY FULL.</b></font>");
  client.println("</div><br><hr>");
  client.println("</body>");
  client.println("</html>");
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: remove the `#endif`

Comment: You probably could have found this out yourself by just reading what the error message says. Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/blog/developers/arduino-programming-for-beginners) will help you get started with coding for the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino IDE gives you a massive clue

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

sketchX:2:2: error: #endif without #if

 #endif

  ^~~~~

sketchX:3:10: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory

 #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
#endif without #if

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

That's pointing at lines #2 & #3 in the sketch as having the error. So we fix those and try again

```
//#endif
```

I'll also install the ESP8266 stuff since that's missing on my new laptop.

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new 
can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, 
DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower 
Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\winuser\Arduino\sketchX\sketchX.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketchX:42:3: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token

   < WiFiClient client = server.available();

   ^

sketchX:42:16: error: expected primary-expression before 'client'

   < WiFiClient client = server.available();

                ^

sketchX:42:16: error: expected ';' before 'client'

sketchX:43:8: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope

   if (!client) {

        ^

sketchX:49:11: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope

   while (!client.available()) {

           ^

sketchX:54:20: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope

   String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');

                    ^

sketchX:4:21: error: 'D2' was not declared in this scope

 #define watersensor D2

                     ^

C:\Users\winuser\Arduino\sketchX\sketchX.ino:79:19: note: in expansion of 
macro 'watersensor'

   if (digitalRead(watersensor) == LOW)

                   ^

exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '<' token

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

So all in all it's simple to use the messages that the IDE gives you to find your error and correct them, working from top to bottom in your sketch. It's not something that needs to be posted on StackExchange until you've corrected the basics.